# Как не отображать компонент в определенных урлах?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Всем привет.
Я использую angular4 и ts. У меня есть общий компонент:

```
<div class="container-full">
<div id="wrapper">

    <app-header-component></app-header-component>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <app-content-component></app-content-component>
        </div>
    </div>

  <app-footer-component></app-footer-component>
```

В `app-header-component` содержится компонент с меню. В `app-content-component` отображатся компоненты из роута. На страницах логи и регистрации мне нужно не показывать меню. Как это лучше сделать ?
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

`<app-header-component *ngIf="showMenu"></app-header-component>`

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  router.events.subscribe((url: any) => {
    this.url = url.url;
    if (this.url.indexOf('/login') === 0 || this.url.indexOf('/register') === 0) {
      this.showMenu = false;
    } else {
       this.showMenu = true;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: в качестве альтернативы можно использовать именное view для роута и в него ложить этот компонент